# How do I check if iOS device is set to "do not disturb"?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

Is there a way to check if user selected "do not disturb" mode? My app relies on some push notifications and I want to inform user, that he should disable "do not disturb" mode for better experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible using the public APi's available.

Comment: And if you use a Private API, Apple will reject your app.

Comment: what is the private api for it?

Answer (score 0):

"Do not Disturb" mode not possible Programmatically.