# iOS swift code to check whether do not disturb mode is enabled in iphone

Tags: ios, swift

I know that there is no way to enable or disable Do not disturb mode through code. But is there a way to check whether its enabled or disabled in the phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect DND mode within an app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17560765/how-can-i-detect-dnd-mode-within-an-app)

Comment: I don't thing it is possible refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976453/can-you-programmatically-toggle-do-not-disturb-mode-in-ios-8-w-swift

Comment: Thanks @chiragshah. This helps a lot

Comment: @vedhanish happy coding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if iOS device is set to "do not disturb"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376383/how-do-i-check-if-ios-device-is-set-to-do-not-disturb)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376383/how-do-i-check-if-ios-device-is-set-to-do-not-disturb